# Programmatically select today's date on Slicer

Tags: vba, excel

I need to choose a slicer item for today's date via VBA. I have tried two methods:

1. Using the SlicerItems method, but SlicerItems causes a

   > Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-define error

   error message, even when I use the simplest version:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
   ```

   I have tried every variation on this that I can, including specifying the cache by name, but I always get the same error.
2. I recorded a macro, which generates a line that does run, and selects the specific slicer item:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("<NAME>").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[VCC IntervalDate].[Hierarchy].[Year Number].&[2015].&[October].&[2015-10-13T00:00:00]")
   ```

   I am then able to use a variable to modify the [2015] and [October] values in the array and have a successful result. However I am unable to modify [2015-10-13T00:00:00] using a variable. It returns an OLAP error.

   If I modify that value manually to the date I need, and it matches the year/month values set via the variable, it works fine:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_VCC_IntervalDate.Hierarchy").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[VCC IntervalDate].[Hierarchy].[Year Number].&[" & Year(d) & "].&[" & Month(d) & "].&[2015-10-14T00:00:00]")
   ```

I have verified the format of the variable outputs the correct format to match `2015-10-14T00:00:00`, but it does not accept it. I've also tried to modify only the date portion and manually input the `T00:00:00` section, but that didn't work either.

So I'm officially stumped and welcome any help.

Comment: Your slicer is associated with a normal Pivot table or a with Power Pivot?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code that didn't work?

Comment: This is Power Pivot. The data source is a SQL data cube. I suspect that is part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a single slicer item, is the opposite of what you expect. Instead of selecting today, you need to deselect all of the other dates.

Give this code a try.
Replace "Slicer_Date" with your cache's name, and change the date format to match your data.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems.Count 'looping through all items
    If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems(i).Value <> Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy") Then 'if date doesn't match then
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems(i).Selected = False 'deselects all other dates
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This matches code I've tried to use previously, but I'm stuck with the same issue as method one above. It errors out whenever I try to use 'SlicerItems'. I get a Run-time error '1004' at the first line in your solution. Is it possible this is because I'm using Power Pivot?

Comment: That is possible. I tested my solution with a regular piovt table.